# can we call a database using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have created a html file,Now am creating next file to call a database from localhost using only AJAX code, is there any way to call a database & to retrieve the data from the database using AJAX code..Here is my code given below..

data.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My DATABASE</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>EMPLOYEE DATABASE</h1>
    <center><div data-role="page" id="pageone">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome To My DATABASE</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <p>Welcome!</p><br><br>
        <img src="logo.png"></img></p><br>
        <a href="#pagetwo" data-role="button" data-inline="true">View Employee</a><br>
        <a href="#pagetwo" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Add Employee</a>
      </div>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

empl.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>LIST OF EMPLOYEE</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
      $.ajax({
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "123";
        $databaseName = "student1";
        $tableName = "employee";
        $con = mysql_connect($localhost,$root,$123);
        $dbs = mysql_select_db($student, $con);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $employee");        
        $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                            
        echo json_encode($array);
       }
      });      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1> EMPLOYEES</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not this way. Ajax call is made client-side, and you don't have access to the database here (maybe you do but it's not a good practice). You have to call a script server-side, which will communicate with database. You can use PHP or Node.js or anything else which will execute on the server directly.

Comment: the answer is; NO! why would you even want to do this unless you're running out of money to pay your bills and you need insurance to pay out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what type of database you are using. They may have some webservices running on the database server that gives you access to the database.
However accessing a database directly from javascript using AJAX **is a really bad practise** and opens security holes.
I would highly advice you to create your own web-service and access the data through it.

Comment: +1. I'd also say that while at first glance it may seem like less work to use something like SQLServer's xml/http capability, apart from the security issues it's actually less work to write a simple piece of PHP/ASP.NET/etc. that produces XML that's easy for the javascript to use. That "simple" may not be so simple in some cases, but in the cases where the PHP/ASP.NET/etc. is complicated, the approach of directly accessing the database would likely be even more complicated anyway.

Comment: Actually JSON is much easier for javascript to use and much more common in combination with AJAX. ASP.NET (and I suppose PHP too) have built in support for web-services that respond using the JSON format

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a application without front end code.

Then go with [Parse](https://parse.com/).

Using parse you can save data from client code, it provides it own database storage.